# Spring update Entity with entity that was created in same transcation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a case where I create an entity, and I would like to save that newly created entity as part of another object. However, when I run my code, there are no errors, yet the value is not saved in the database.

Here is the code that creates the entity and stores it in another entity

```
Info persisted = infoService.create(info);
account.setInfo(persisted);
update(account);
```

The code to update is as follows:

```
@Override
public void update(final T entity) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(entity);

    getDao().save(entity);
}
```

The save method is as follows:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After to `persist` or `update` an entity your should `flush` in order to synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database as it is mentioned in documentation, 
then you might create a method called **saveAndFlush** and call your method, later you can use as this:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity) {

    S result = save(entity);
    em.flush();

    return result;
}
```